# Static files are being collected, but they don't want to work on local server

Tags: python, django

As someone relatively new in Web Development in Django I'm struggling with the staticfiles within my project. Whenever I take some prepared bootstrap template something is not working, same when I try to add some javascript - and have no idea why. I tried to find the answer before, but in theory, everything should work - would be awesome if someone could guide me, cuz I feel completely lost now. Everything works fine until I want to use some advanced js/css animations.

It looks like in the image - the main background doesn't load, the navibar is shattered as well.

[image]

My settings I think look fine - Django collect all the static files, but they don't want to work on the local server. Everything is rooted in views.py/urls.py

Also here is the tree of the whole project

[image]

```
    """
Django settings for alexxx project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = my code is hereeeeee, so I hid it cuzthe warning says so, lol

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'site12'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'alexxx.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'alexxx.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

---

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WHY YOU DONT WORK DJANGO</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <meta content="" name="description">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
  <link href="{% static 'lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
  <link href="{% static 'lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'lib/animate/animate.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
  <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`</head>
```

(some code here)

```
<!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
  <script src="{% static 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/easing/easing.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/superfish/hoverIntent.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/superfish/superfish.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/wow/wow.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/counterup/counterup.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- Contact Form JavaScript File -->
  <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main Javascript File -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Adding urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And the project one:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('site12.urls'))
]
```

And the views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html')
```

Comment: Please, add your `urls.py`

Comment: I added both urls.py and views.py as well. The application is added in the settings' Installed Apps as well.

Comment: Is DEBUG=True in settings.py?

Comment: Yes it is, I added the whole settings to the post if you want, cause this time I have absolutely no clue where the mistake is hidden.

Comment: In chrome and Firefox you can hit F12. In the "console" tab it might tell you where it's looking and hitting an error

Comment: I'd check where BASE_DIR points, maybe path.join builds an incorrect path.

Comment: There's only one error - concerning the not loaded image. Which doesn't explain the whole rest of js and some css that doesn't work.

Using the URLconf defined in alexxx.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, img/overlay-bg.jpg, didn't match any of these.

Comment: BASE_Dir path seems to be correct: 

base dir path C:\Users\SAD\PycharmProjects\alexxx

Comment: Hmm... If you open in the browser e.g. `/static/css/style.css` will it load?

Comment: try to make the `{% load static %}` before `<!DOCTYPE html>`